# Error 5: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataSet' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Sorry for the noobiness here but I'm having an issue with the following SQL connection in C# asp.net

```
   #region Get Employee Logins

    DataSet ds_Logins;
    SqlDataAdapter da_Logins;

    SqlCommand cmdLogins = new SqlCommand("IFACE_SB_EMPLOYEE", SBConn.sbConn);
    cmdLogins.Parameters.Add("@Statement", SqlDbType.Char).Value = "GetLogins";
    cmdLogins.Parameters.Add("@i_FK_EmployeeID", SqlDbType.Char).Value = Request["i_FK_EmployeeID"].Trim().ToString();
    cmdLogins.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    da_Logins = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdLogins);

    try
    {
        SBConn.sbConn.Open();

        da_Logins = new DataSet();
        int row = da_Logins.Fill(ds_Logins, "SB_SST_EXCHANGERATE");

        if (row <= 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            GridViewSystemsLogin.DataSource = ds_Logins.Tables[0];
            GridViewSystemsLogin.DataBind();
        }

        SBConn.sbConn.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception )
    {
    }

    #endregion
```

Can anybody help me with what the pickle is wrong we it seeing as its been copied from an existing working file and re-jigged in the stored procedure and table aspects.

Thanks

Marcus

Comment: A general hint: Don't do stuff like `catch (Exception) {}`. Errors should never pass silently. In addition, if you don't catch the exception, Visual Studio will tell you exactly *which* line caused the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line

```
da_Logins = new DataSet();
```

should read

```
ds_Logins = new DataSet();
```

Comment: @user1052110 BTW: If you had choosen "speaking" names, you would have easier found that error. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for that. Been looking at this for too long obviously. Tea break required i think

Comment: @user1052110: Glad to help. Please mark it as "accepted answer" by clicking on the green check mark, so that people know this question has been answered.

Comment: Sorry took me a while been hectic. Thanks though :)